# Polar Coordinates Integral (doughnut)

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

Let $\Omega={B}_1(0)/B_{\epsilon}(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ contínuous and $S^1$ be the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.
I want to evaluate the integral
$$I:=\int_{\Omega}f(x)dx.$$

My question is:

Is $I$ equal

$$\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\int_{S^1}f(rx)dxdr ?$$

I tried polar coordinates but didn't when too far.

Comment: You need a sphere $S^{n-1}$ and a bit stronger assumptions on your $f$. Then you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: It is apparent that you mean $B_1(0)\setminus B_\epsilon(0)$ (that is `\setminus`), which is an annular hyper-ball, not a doughnut. FYI - $B_1(0)/B_\epsilon(0)$ denotes the topological result of collapsing the entire inner ball to a point inside the outer ball (the result of which is just another ball).

Comment: You also need $$\iint f(rx)\color{red}rdxdr$$ (You mentioned polar coordinates, but remember that in the plane $dA = rd\theta dr$, not $d\theta dr$.)